# How does Rails autoload work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a definitive guide or some good blog posts to understand how the autoload works in Rails 3? The "file not found" and "uninitialized constant" errors are so common and **so**, **so** frustrating.

What parts of the autoload mechanism are "from Ruby" and what are "from Rails"? How does it all work? Why can it not find files when they clearly exist in the correct location? And if it finds the files why does it complain of "uninitialized constant"?

Or is it just me being bad even after using Rails for a year?

Answer (score 3):

It uses `Kernel#autoload`. From ri:

```
= Kernel#autoload

(from ~/.ri)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  autoload(module, filename)   -> nil

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Registers filename to be loaded (using Kernel::require) the
first time that module (which may be a String or a symbol) is
accessed.

  autoload(:MyModule, "/usr/local/lib/modules/my_module.rb")
```

About the problems you are having with "file not found" errors, can you add the details of a specific example to your question? That will make it easier to help you.

Answer (score 1):

IMO the best resource on autoloading and reloading in Rails is the Rails Guides chapter on the topic http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html

In order to understand how this Rails mechanism works, you need to make sure you understand how Ruby constant lookup works and what are the different ways of loading code in Ruby.

It is not an easy topic, as is explained in this detailed blog post from Konstantin Haase the creator of Sinatra. http://blog.rkh.im/code-reloading.